# Take content from one text file and put it in another with PHP?

Tags: php

i need help with this one , is there any ways when i amend `file1.txt` to send the old information to `file2.txt` and so on. I have 4 files like this and i want to swap the content inside them when `file1.txt` is changed .

Like this when content in first one changed send old content in the chain `file1.txt` --> `file2.txt` --> `file3.txt`--> `file4.txt`

thats my php file

```php
$myfile = fopen("file1.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, "Today we had 11 people");
fclose($myfile);
```

my idea is to send This content of strings `"Today we had 11 people"` to second file , when content in `file1.txt` is changed to lets say  `"Today we had 23 people"`

Comment: What do you mean by "amend" and "old information"? Please clarify your question, and show what you've tried to resolve the problem

Comment: I think you better copy the first file, before you change the first file content. is it what you need? if not explain clear why not? Also please put a clear example of what you done till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy/pragmatic way to do that would be copy the files in the chain.

```php
function copyFiles(string $newLine): void
{

    exec("cp path/to/file3.txt path/to/file4.txt");    
    exec("cp path/to/file2.txt path/to/file3.txt");
    exec("cp path/to/file1.txt path/to/file2.txt");

    exec("echo $newLine >> path/to/file1.txt");
}
```

**Note:** For this approach, you may need to talk to your host to see if it is allowed at all. not every host allows `cp` commands via php exec.

**suggestion from @Will**

You can also use the rename() function instead of exec() for this.
`rename("/test/file1.txt","/home/docs/my_file.txt");`

Comment: Well, why not use the php rename() function ?

Comment: @Will Yes, that should work with it too. I haven't used the php rename() function yet and therefore didn't think of it! Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @Maik Lowrey for the answer , how he noted `cp` is not allowed on my host. Instead of that i used the idea of @Will and worked perfectly ! THANK YOU BOTH :)

```
function copyFiles(string $newLine): void
{

    rename( "file3.txt", "file4.txt");    
    rename("file2.txt", "file3.txt");
    rename("file1.txt", "file2.txt");

    exec("echo $newLine >> file1.txt");
}
```

Comment: your echo approach is vulnerable to [shell injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection)! imagine if a hacker is able to make the command ```echo foo; rm -rfv *; echo bar >> file1.txt;``` !  also not every host allow exec() (often for security reasons, like the shell injection); the last line should instead be ```file_put_contents("file1.txt",$newLine."\n", FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);```

Comment: @AlevMustafa You welcome. And good hint from hanshenrik